# jQuery: Hiding a button for 3 seconds. setInterval/.hide, or toggleClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, setinterval, toggleclass

I'm looking for some quick advice. I'm a student new to `Javascript`, and I have been tasked with making a simple game. One of the elements of this game is to have a button called "attack" which disappears for three seconds every time it is pressed. It then reappears.

I have been looking at the different codes I can do with this, and I was wondering if anyone has any recs as to what is easier to use, and also just some help with syntax. My initial thoughts were to do this:

In JS file:

```
var attack_button = $('.attack');
attack_button.click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('invisible');
```

In CSS file:

```
.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

However, is there a timer that can easily be set on toggleClass to only make it last for three seconds?

I was also thinking I could do this:

In JS file:

```
setInterval(function() {
    attack_button.hide() }, 3000 }
```

Any suggestions? I won't be able to consult with instructors for a few days and I'd like to get some work in now.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `setTimeout();`

**I think this is the code you need**

```
var attack_button = $('.attack');
attack_button.click(function() {
  var ThisIt = $(this);
  ThisIt.addClass('invisible');
  setTimeout(function(){
    ThisIt.removeClass('invisible');
  } , 3000);
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/qg2xndk6/1/)

[**Demo with Fade Effect**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/qg2xndk6/2/)

> Note: be sure to include jquery